# TASM how to remove first two characters of a string

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I have a problem. I have a function that inputs a string from the console. But when outputting, it also outputs 2 incomprehensible characters. It seems that this is due to the fact that the first two bytes contain the maximum and actual length of the string. I think you just need to move the pointer and then the line will be displayed correctly. But to be honest, I don’t understand how exactly this needs to be done.

```
assume cs: code, ds: data

data segment
first db 255, 254 dup (0)
second db 255, 254 dup (0)
data ends

code segment


input proc
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 0Ah
  int 21h
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  inc dx
  mov si, dx
  mov cx, [si]
  xor ch, ch
  add si, cx
  mov byte ptr [si+1], '$'
  inc dx
  
  pop bp
  ret
input endp

print proc
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  
  pop bp
  ret
print endp

endl proc
  mov ah, 02h
  mov dl, 0Ah
  int 21h
  ret
endl endp



main:
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax

  push offset first
  call input
  call endl
  call print
  call endl
  
  push offset second
  call input
  call endl
  call print
  call endl
  

  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h
  code ends
    end main
```

I tried to move the dx, but I think it's wrong, because it doesn't work. I don’t really understand how to make the changes saved after exiting the input

Comment: In `print` after `mov dx, [bp + 4]` try adding `inc dx` twice.

Comment: @ecm, It did not help. In general, I don't necessarily need to remove the first two characters of the line. I need to implement a strsmp function similar to the one in the C programming language. Would it be better to just skip two characters when comparing strings, rather than removing two characters?

Comment: That should have helped, you did something wrong. Nevertheless it's not the best solution to have a `print` function (or any other function) that just knows to skip 2 bytes. You should instead pass the argument already adjusted. Remove the argument you passed to `input` and `push offset first + 2` for the `print`.

Comment: @Jester. I added the line `add dx, 2` after the line `mov dx, [bp+4]` in the print function and it worked, thanks